# How to make application window sizes fit within smaller screen dimensions on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, screen

This is my first question so forgive my inconsistencies in Stack Exchange writing convention.

I am using a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B connected to a 5" (800*480px) HDMI touchscreen.
[Here is the Amazon link for the exact screen I am using: https://www.amazon.com/Elecrow-Capacitive-interface-Supports-Raspberry/dp/B07FDYXPT7/]

My setup seems to be functional, the screen interfaces with the RPI properly and it detected it's proportions instantly after a restart, however, my problem is that some application windows are too large to fit within the screen borders.  I am aware that I can hold the left Alt key while dragging a window to reposition it, but due to my application, this can be somewhat tedious to do all the time.

I prefer not to use any virtual machine or non-Raspbian (current installed OS) operating system to fix this issue, I simply wanted to know if there are any ways to decrease the sizes of all application windows without modifying the resolution/ratio of the display.

Here are some other similar questions that I have read to reference, (none have sufficiently solved my issue.):

- [Fit contents of screen to small display](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/130446/fit-contents-of-screen-to-small-display)
- [Touch Screen Window Size Adjuster](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32061/touch-screen-window-size-adjuster)
- [Force Raspbian to display everything a little bit smaller](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36288/force-raspbian-to-display-everything-a-little-bit-smaller/43925#43925)

Here is some extra information:

- Display.Overscan is disabled.
- Screen is connected to RPI via Micro-HDMI 0 to the HDMI port on the display.
- Using Raspbian OS with desktop and recommended software.

Comment: some apps may have a minimum window size that is larger than the screen

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.. The application windows I use are just big enough so that when I view the content of the window the minimize, maximize, and close buttons are obscured.  I guess an alternative is to memorize keyboard shortcuts to do all those things.

Comment: it's been a while since I used linux ... used to be able to define a virtual window that is larger than the physical window ... the physical window is a viewport into the virtual window ... dragging a cursor to the edge of screen would shift the viewport into the virtual window ... look into that ... and don't limit your chances of success by focusing at RPi websites ... the problem is related to linux